# How to encode characters from Oracle to XML?

Tags: java, xml, oracle, encoding

In my environment here I use Java to serialize the result set to XML.
It happens basically like this:

```
//foreach column of each row
xmlHandler.startElement(uri, lname, "column", attributes);
String chars = rs.getString(i);
xmlHandler.characters(chars.toCharArray(), 0, chars.length());
xmlHandler.endElement(uri, lname, "column");
```

The XML looks like this in Firefox:

```
<row num="69004">
    <column num="1">10069</column>
    <column num="2">sd&#26;</column>
    <column num="3">FCVolume                      </column>
</row>
```

But when I parse the XML I get the a

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "**&#26**" is an
>   invalid XML character.

My question now is: Which charactes do I have to replace or how do I have to encode my characters, that they will be valid XML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an interesting list in the [Xml Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#charsets):
According to that List its discouraged to use the Character #26 (Hex: *#x1A*).

> The characters defined in the
>   following ranges are also discouraged.
>   They are either control characters or
>   permanently undefined Unicode
>   characters

See the [complete ranges](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#charsets).

This code replaces all non-valid Xml Utf8 from a String:

```
public String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(String in) {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(); // Used to hold the output.
    char current; // Used to reference the current character.

    if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) return ""; // vacancy test.
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        current = in.charAt(i);
        if ((current == 0x9) ||
            (current == 0xA) ||
            (current == 0xD) ||
            ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
            ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
            ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF)))
            out.append(current);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

its taken from [Invalid XML Characters: when valid UTF8 does not mean valid XML](http://cse-mjmcl.cse.bris.ac.uk/blog/2007/02/14/1171465494443.html)

But with that I had the still UTF-8 compatility issue:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence
```

After reading [XML - returning XML as UTF-8 from a servlet](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t166758-returning-xml-as-utf8-from-a-servlet.html) I just tried out what happens if I set the Contenttype like this:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=utf-8");
```

And it worked ....

Answer (score 2):

[Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) says:

> The ampersand character (&) and the
>   left angle bracket (<) must not appear
>   in their literal form, except when
>   used as markup delimiters, or within a
>   comment, a processing instruction, or
>   a CDATA section. If they are needed
>   elsewhere, they must be escaped using
>   either numeric character references or
>   the strings "&" and "<"
>   respectively. The right angle bracket
>   (>) may be represented using the
>   string ">", and must, for
>   compatibility, be escaped using either
>   ">" or a character reference when
>   it appears in the string "]]>" in
>   content, when that string is not
>   marking the end of a CDATA section.

You can skip the encoding if you use CDATA:

```
<column num="1"><![CDATA[10069]]></column>
<column num="2"><![CDATA[sd&]]></column>
```

Comment: That would be a good solution, but I don't know how to output a CDATA section (I can only work with a sax xml handler and have no access to the stream itself). And if I put the CDATA in the chars, the <'s get encoded to >....

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JRE are you running? [Sax Project](http://www.saxproject.org/faq.html) says:

> J2SE 1.4 bundles an old version of
>   SAX2. How do I make SAX2 r2 or later available?