# How to output a CDATA section from a Sax XmlHandler

Tags: java, xml, sax

This is a followup question of [How to encode characters from Oracle to Xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156697/how-to-encode-characters-from-oracle-to-xml)

In my environment here I use Java to serialize the result set to xml. I have no access to the output stream itself, only to a org.xml.sax.ContentHandler.

When I try to output characters in a CDATA Section:

It happens basically like this:

```
xmlHandler.startElement(uri, lname, "column", attributes);
String chars = "<![CDATA["+rs.getString(i)+"]]>";
xmlHandler.characters(chars.toCharArray(), 0, chars.length());
xmlHandler.endElement(uri, lname, "column");
```

I get this:

```
<column>&lt;![CDATA[33665]]&gt;</column>
```

But I want this:

```
<column><![CDATA[33665]]></column>
```

So how can I output a CDATA section with a Sax ContentHandler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is getting escaped because the handler.characters function is designed to escape and the `<![CDATA[` part isn't considered part of the value.

You need to use the newly exposed methods in `DefaultHandler2` or use the `TransformerHandler` approach where you can set the output key `CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS`, which takes a whitespace delimited list of tag names that should output sub text sections enclosed in CDATA.

```
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler hd = tf.newTransformerHandler();
Transformer serializer = hd.getTransformer();
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "column");
hd.setResult(streamResult);
hd.startDocument();
hd.startElement("","","column",atts);
hd.characters(asdf,0, asdf.length());
hd.endElement("","","column");
hd.endDocument();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "... DefaultHandler2 **or** use the TransformerHandler", how can I use the DefaultHandler2 methods to output CData tags when I serialize the XML. I am already using the functions `document.createCDATASection(...)` in my code. Is there any way to output CDATA tags without using the `CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS` property?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `startCDATA()` and `endCData()` as delimiters, i.e.

```
xmlHandler.startElement(uri, lname, "column", attributes);
xmlHandler.startCDATA();
String chars = rs.getString(i);
xmlHandler.characters(chars.toCharArray(), 0, chars.length());
xmlHandler.endCDATA();
xmlHandler.endElement(uri, lname, "column");
```