# JAVA SAX DefaultHandler startCDATA() not firing

Tags: java, sax, cdata

I am trying to parse and detect the start of the CDATA within a tag like:

`<child><![CDATA[data goes here]]></child>`

I have a class that extends the Default handler

`class MyXmlDoc extends DefaultHandler{`

with methods for `startElement()` and `endElement()` that fire correctly but the `startCDATA()` never fires. My `characters()` method picks up the 'data goes here' so it appears that the CDATA 'wrapper' is detected but ???

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDATA is a lexical event. Regular handlers (content handler, error handler) do not process these events. You need to set a lexical handler for your reader, if it supports having one. Lexical handler is a SAX2 extension so Java XMLReader uses `setProperty` method for setting it.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29 and http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/LexicalHandler.html

Comment: Thanks! I was able to implement a LexicalHandler and use the setProperty()

Answer (score 1):

Is your data getting escaped in there? how are you writing the xml doc?

This may help you:
[How to output a CDATA section from a Sax XmlHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156777/how-to-output-a-cdata-section-from-a-sax-xmlhandler)

This is pretty verbose too:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/127987/XML/read-cdata-sax-parser