# how to get Python XMLGenerator to output CDATA

Tags: python, xml, sax

This is the Python equivalent of the Java question [How to output a CDATA section from a Sax XmlHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156777/how-to-output-a-cdata-section-from-a-sax-xmlhandler)

Neither [xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator) or [lxml.sax.ElementTreeContentHandler](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.sax.ElementTreeContentHandler-class.html) says anything about CDATA sections. How can I get it to output CDATA?

Answer (score 9):

You could do it straight in your code using

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator


xml = XMLGenerator()
xml.startDocument()
xml.startElement('item', {})
content = '<p>Stuff</p>'
cdata = '<![CDATA[{}]]>'.format(content)
xml.ignorableWhitespace(cdata)
xml.endElement('item')
xml.endDocument()
```

Or extend the XMLGenerator class with a new function

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator


class _XMLGenerator(XMLGenerator):
    def cdata(self, content):
        cdata = '<![CDATA[{}]]>'.format(content)
        self.ignorableWhitespace(cdata)

xml = _XMLGenerator()
xml.startDocument()
xml.startElement('item', {})
content = '<p>Stuff</p>'
xml.cdata(content)
xml.endElement('item')
xml.endDocument()
```

The reason I don't use `xml.characters(content)` is because it calls the `xml.sax.saxutils.escape` function, which in turns escapes &, < and >.

Answer (score 2):

You can use xml.dom.minidom
like this:

```
doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
article = doc.createElement('article')
content = doc.createCDATASection('<p>Any CDATA</p>')
article.appendChild(content)
```

Comment: Yes, the `Document.createCDATASection()` method works, but it is missing from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html#document-objects.