# Writing CDATA section to XML file

Tags: python, xml, cdata

I'm trying to create an xml file mimicing another applications xml file. I can't figure out how to write the following line to xml...

`<![CDATA[execfile("C:\users\me\run.py")]]>`

it always wants to convert it to

`&lt;![CDATA[execfile(&quot;C:\users\me\run.py&quot;)]]&gt;`

The complete output currently looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shelfDocument>
    <tool name="MyTool" label="MyTool">
        <script scriptType="python">&lt;![CDATA[execfile(&quot;C:\users\me\run.py&quot;)]]&gt;</script>
    </tool>
</shelfDocument>
```

I need it to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shelfDocument>
    <tool name="MyTool" label="MyTool">
        <script scriptType="python">
            <![CDATA[execfile("C:\users\me\run.py")]]>
        </script>
    </tool>
</shelfDocument>
```

here is my python code...

```
import os
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('shelfDocument')
scriptItemEl = ET.SubElement(root, 'tool', name='MyTool', label='MyTool')

cmd = '<![CDATA[execfile("{}")]]>'.format('C:\\users\\me\\run.py')
scriptEl = ET.SubElement(scriptItemEl, 'script', scriptType='python')
scriptEl.text = '{}'.format(cmd)

xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8', method="xml")
xmlObj = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlstr)
xmlstr = xmlObj.toprettyxml(encoding='UTF-8')

filepath = 'output.xml'
with open(filepath, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(xmlstr)
```

Comment: Just use XSLT for your task. XSLT supports CData sections.

Comment: I'm trying to stick to default python libraries

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/174890/407651

Comment: Or maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35760157/407651

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55150569/317052

Comment: Use this

root.createCDATASection(r'execfile("C:\users\me\run.py")')

where

r is python raw string